# Android: Initialize some strings that can be used anywhere in the project

Tags: java, android

In my Android application, when i login to the application, i receive a set of strings which i'm saving using `Shared Preferences`.

These strings are nothing but the text that must be assigned to the `TextView's`, hints for the `EditText's` etc. throughout the application.

Eg. Say my application has 4 activities. Each activity has say 10 labels/TextViews. So totally on login i'll be receiving 40 strings and i'm storing it in shared preferences based on some logic. My question is is there a way i can have 40 strings declared somewhere and initialized on login (instead of storing in Shared Preferences). And i must be able to use this strings throughout my application? Which is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *i receive a set of strings* from where ?

Comment: I make a Service call which sends me a JSON object which contains key value pairs. This values are the strings.

Comment: Are all your Strings constant?

Comment: do you always call this service on Login activity???

Comment: yes the service is always called

Comment: Yes all of them are string constants received in form of key value pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by extending `android.app.Application`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private HashMap<String, String> variables = new HashMap<>();

    public String getVariable(String key) {
        return variables.get(key);
    }

    public void setVariable(String key, String value) {
        variables.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

and in manifest

```
<application 
  android:name="MyApplication" 
  android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name">
    ....
</application>
```

and do this in your activity where you want to get the variable

```
// set variable
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setVariable("key1", "value1");
// get variable
String value1 = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getVariable("key1");
```

Comment: In case i'm trying to access this  hashmap variable from onClick of a Button, then "this" keyword does'nt work. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
android.app.Application:
Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
```

To me it sounds like the strings are just part of the application state. Create a subclass of Application, register that class in AndroidManifest.xml as your application class and store the strings there. Then you can access the strings from all of your activity classes by calling getApplication()...